# How To Re-Locate Working Copy In SourceTree

Tags: xcode, atlassian-sourcetree

I have a repository added to SourceTree.  When I commit a change to the remote repository through XCode I see the change get committed remotely but my working copy doesn't get updated in SourceTree app.  I have to rebase the changes to master in SourceTree.  This is because my working copy folder is set to the wrong location in SourceTree.

How can I change the location of the local working copy folder in SourceTree?

Comment: Just delete the one you are using and add the one that Xcode is using.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The easiest way is to move your old Working Copy (rename the folder).
When you start SourceTree next time, SourceTree wants you to set the new "Working Copy" folder of the repository.

https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/43326/change-working-copy-location

Comment: That worked for me, except I had SourceTree Did not prompt me to change the path upon re-opening SourcTree.  Instead I was able to do so by double clicking the local repo in SourceTree (that then prompted me).

Comment: Can I invoke this without renaming the folder? I have a folder and a symlink to it which is used by SourceTree. This unfortunately yields unforeseen issues, so I want to point it to the OG directory without having to rename.

Comment: Got it `%localappdata%\Atlassian\SourceTree\bookmarks.xml`

Answer (score 7):

Another way is to adjust the entry in sourcetree's bookmarks xml file

```
%localappdata%\Atlassian\SourceTree\bookmarks.xml
```

e.g.

```
C:\Users\Qwerty\AppData\Local\Atlassian\SourceTree
```