# Windows - How To Re-Locate Working Copy (Move Local Repo) In SourceTree?

Tags: windows, git, atlassian-sourcetree

I just re-organize my files/folders in my PC, so I need to update the new local project's path for Source Tree. I did this thing before but I think it would be quicker to Google than to look for my old notes, but strangely Google didn't give me the answer I want, for example: I found these:

- [How To Re-Locate Working Copy In SourceTree (for XCode)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19118421)
- [Change working copy location](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Sourcetree-questions/Change-working-copy-location/qaq-p/452647)
- [Moved local repository](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Sourcetree-questions/Moved-local-repository/qaq-p/72312)

I want to find the file that contains the path of Local Repo so I can just quickly replace all with Notepad.

(Actually I've already figured out how to do this, I make this question to share my solution)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I want to find the file that contains the path of Local Repo so I can
>   just quickly replace all with Notepad.

The file you want is `bookmarks.xml` which is located at: `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Atlassian\SourceTree\bookmarks.xml`